# How to change the api url by changing the dropdown from html in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I am trying to call the service call with changing the dropdown. Here is my code

.html

```
 <select class="form-control" name="monthSelection" id="monthSelectionTab" (change)="onMonthSelectionTabChanged($event)">
                <option value="1">This month</option>
                <option value="0">Previous month</option>
            </select>
```

.ts

```
onMonthSelectionTabChanged(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }
```

.service

```
 getUpdatenRecords(userId: number): any {
    return this.http.get(this.mainUrl + '/getcurrin/' + userId)
  }
```

I want to change the mainUrl as when `this month` is selected like `localhost:8000/getcurrin/4/1`

and when `previous month` is selected like `localhost:8000/getcurrin/4/0`

any help.

Comment: To achieve this you need to read [Angular Router](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Answer (score 1):

Typically you want to keep your service and component logic independent of each other. as such, if a service will react differently based on parameters, you should look to pass those parameters into the service call.

Service

```
getUpdatenRecords(userId: number, monthSelection: number = 0): any {
    return this.http.get(`${this.mainUrl}/${monthSelection}/${userId}`);
}
```

This way the service can be independent of the component logic. in this case `monthSelection` defaults to 0 if not provided.

Then modify your component event handler to pass the attribute to the service call.

Component

```
onMonthSelectionTabChanged(event) {
    this.service.getUpdatenRecords(this.userId, event).subscribe();
}
```

make sure to also unsubscribe from the obsvervable in the ngOnDestroy method.

Hope this is useful. good luck.

Comment: When I record in the network tab the service calls are not happening and the data is also not reflecting when I change the dropdown.

Comment: I have implemented the same but i am not getting the result.

Comment: you need to subscribe to the observable returned from `onMothSelectionTabChanged` method. by default Observables are 'cold'. meaning that if you want trigger the event, you need to subscribe to it.
i.e. `this.service.getUpdatenRecords(this.userId, event).subscribe();`
You will need to make sure to unsubcribe when you are done.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change baseUrl of your call you should use Interceptor for that.